# Setting HotSpot(TM) Server VM in Java 1.6 environment

Tags: java

I have a question related to setting Java hotspot server VM in java 1.6

is there any way to set Java HotSpot Server VM in java 1.6 environment? When i run following command

java -version

it's showing as below,

java version "1.6.0_16"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_16-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 14.2-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

I want this has to be displayed as below in third line.

Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 14.2-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

Is there any command so that whenever we run java -version, it will always show Hotspot Server VM rather Client VM??

Thanks
Robert.

Answer (score 4):

Add the -server flag:

`java -version -server`

outputs

```
java version "1.6.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 17.0-b16, mixed mode)
```

Comment: i believe, that for it to work, you need to put the -server before the -version .

Comment: Order is not important for flags.

Answer (score 2):

You should try 'java -server -version' instead. You will need to have the server hotspot compiler installed or use that on the JRE that comes bundled with the JDK (which comes with server hotstpot).

Comment: Yes. I am using with JRE. by running this, it just shows Server VM whenever i run java -server -version. I want the output to show always

Comment: Hotspot server VM whenever i run Java -version

Comment: You can't... but a hack would be to map 'java' command to a custom script that add the '-server' flag in args if not present ... btw, I don't think it's a good idea !

Answer (score 2):

I seem to remember reading somewhere that the JVM will start in server mode automatically if the system meets certain specifications in terms of number of processes and amount of memory. Can't remember the details or find the info though.

Edit: Found some info here
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html

Server class machine is > 2Gb RAM and > 2 processors.

Comment: I have a machine which has 3.21 GB RAM and 2 processors(looked in to Sysmte properties->hardware-Device drivers). I have installed JAva 1.6. it still doesn't show Hotspot Server VM when i run java -version. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Robo `java -server -version`

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the '-server' flag !